# how to make ubuntu send sms via connected gsm mobile phone each time false login attempts are made?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

how can i make a system running ubuntu send me sms alerts?
i want that as and when any intruder tries to login to my system [which is running ubuntu 12.04 LTS] a sms alert should sent on a pre fixed number via a gsm module [mobile phone] connected to my ubuntu system.

Comment: If you don't get an answer to this question over here, you might try over at http://serverfault.com/ later on.

Comment: You could use Google Voice to send a SMS instead of a GSM Phone. May be easier to interface with. There are some python extensions with API calls to Google Voice that allows sending of SMS text messages. You would just need to build a service that runs in the background that is triggered whenever a failed login attempt occurs.

Comment: Alternatively you could use an Email->SMS gateway. The Ubuntu box just emails to a specific address, which the gateway then forwards as an SMS.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm telling you here is related but not really an answer, I hope it's useful anyway.

I know an application for android devices, named [easySMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fireblade.easysms&hl=en). Basically you can send sms from your mobile, connected in the same lan, or via USB/Bluetooth. After installing that, you'll have an applicatin running without root privileges (afaik) listening on port 2511 (default).

you are supposed to connect to that port, and you want to automatize the process.
What I'd try if I were you is to write a script collecting the information you want to send via SMS, and then use e.g.

```
curl –user :<username>:<password> “http://<ip>:<port> /newmessage?text=<messagemax 160car>&empf=<mobile>&type=send”
```

hope it helps!